# Most efficient way to have a page that has a vast amount of results depending on request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The best example i can think of is a hall of fame page for sports.

You can then have a navigation that can limit the results depending on the user's requests, Past 3 Months and boxing for example.

What would be the best way to display multiple kind of result layouts, for example,

The swimming results have a different layout to football, football differs to boxing and then add a time limiter by timestamp.

These are the options i have thought of so far and would like your opinion on.

**Simple PHP**

```
if($_GET['sport'] = "boxing"){
    if(isset($_GET['timescale'])){
        $start = 1334752108;
        $end = 1334759108;
        $query = "SELECT athlete_name, athlete_age, athlete_desc FROM `athletes` WHERE  `timestamp` BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."' AND `sport` = 'boxing' LIMIT 30";
    }   else    {
        $query = "SELECT athlete_name, athlete_age, athlete_desc FROM `athletes` WHERE `sport` = 'boxing' LIMIT 30";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))){
        echo "<div class='boxing'>";
        //show results
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
if($_GET['sport'] = "swimming"){
    //repeated
}
if($_GET['sport'] = "football"){
    //repeated
}
```

**Ajax**

Have either one page that will handle all the requests (ajax_request_hof.php) that contains similar code to the PHP above.

**EDIT**
skafandri suggested a Data Mapping Class, would anyone else advise this or is able to show me an example?

Any ideas on how i can improve this are greatly welcomed and needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in SO chat that you didn't have any experience with frameworks so here's a suggestion without one.

I know I'm probably going to be flamed for this, but knowing that it's an organizational structure issue you can steal some concepts of MVC and use them until you can port it to a more proper structure to at least make it a little cleaner and a lot easier to manage.

*Disclaimer: In no way is this a good structure but for your problem, considering you told me you didn't have any background on OOP and or patterns, but it's "good enough" as a temporary solution.*

If you order it like this you can insert it into almost any framework without doing a lot of work.

Here's one way you can do it.

With the following classes:

```
<?php

class BasketballPage
{
    protected $mapper;

    public construct ( $mapper )
    {
        $this->mapper = $mapper;
    }

    public function display_player_info( $playerid, $sportid )
    {
        $basketball_player = $this->mapper->get_sports_player( $playerid, $sportid )

        echo '<p>Basketball player name ' . $basketball_player['name'];
        echo '<p>Some other HTML, etc</p>';
    }

    public function display_match_data($matchid, $sportid)
    {
        //Same as above but would call to $this_mapper->get_match_data(); And display relevant HTML.
    }

    public function display_player_info_AJAX( $playerid, $sportid )
    {
        $player = $this->mapper->get_sports_player();
        header('Content-type: text/json');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(  $player );
        exit();
    }
}

class BoxingPage
{
    protected $mapper;

    public function display_player_info( $playerid, $sportid)
    {
        $boxing_person = $this->mapper->get_sports_player( $playerid, $sportid)

        echo '<p>Person\'s boxing name ' . $boxing_person['name'];
        echo '<p>Some other HTML, etc</p>';
    }
}

class Mapper
{
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct ( $connection )
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function get_sports_player($id, $sportid)
    {
        $query = $this->connection->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM players WHERE id = :player_id AND sport_id' );
        $query->bindValue(':player_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':sport_id', $sport_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }

    public function get_match_data($matchid, $sportid)
    {
        //some query here that returns match data.
    }
}

?>
```

You'd have a single php page for each of these classes, since they can grow big.
I.e:

- Basketballpage.php
- Boxingpage.php
- Mapper.php

Then include these files into your index.php. and your index could look something like this:

index.php?playerid=1&sportid=2

```
<?php

//Instantiate the classes first.

$connection = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password); //your database credentials
$mapper = new Mapper( $connection );
$basketballpage = new BasketballPage( $mapper );
$boxingpage = new BoxingPage( $mapper );

if( $_GET['page'] == 2]) //lets say basketball is id 2 in your database
{
    $basketballpage->display_player_info( $_GET['playerid'], $_GET['sportid'] );
}

//In this same page you'd also add this other line, but lets say they visit the bottom link instead: index.php?playerid=1&sportid=3

if( $_GET['page'] == 3]) //lets say boxing is 3 in your database
{
    $boxing->display_player_info( $_GET['playerid'], $_GET['sportid'] );
}

//THEN lets say someone visits a different link like: index.php?index.php?matchid=1&sportid=2&page=2

if( $_GET['page'] == 2] && $_GET['matchid'])
{
    $boxingpage->display_match_data( $_GET['playerid'] );
}

//On the above you can use that same category, but a different function will display a different page!

//Bonus example, you can use it for AJAX easily. Lets say they visit the url index.php?playerid=1&sportid=2&AJAX=1


if( $_GET['page'] == 2 && GET['AJAX'] == 1) 
{
    $basketballpage->display_player_info_AJAX( $_GET['playerid'], $_GET['sportid'] );
}

?>
```

It seems complicated but once you see how it's all connected, notice how your index page is only around 30-40 lines! It can make things really neat and you can just concentrate on routing your requests on index.php while the other files take care of the rest.

Comment: This solution completely ignores efficiency.  It has individual queries for each player (when you could have a single query that works for the entire page).

Comment: That was just an example, I don't know how his database is laid out so he obviously has to replace that with his own queries and whatever information he needs on that page.

Comment: It can be assumed from the question that the OP has an athlete table with each athlete having a sport field.

Comment: @Paul Well, the idea is there. This is basically your answer but more in detail and without the view part. He can do as he wishes with it now that he understood.

Answer (score 0):

[EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) is a great solution to handle different data models, you can also write a data mapping class, although I recommend you to use a PHP framework, why not ZEND?

Comment: Could you give an example of a data mapping class? I have a fair understanding of PHP but have built most of my site without a framework and am afraid that i would have to redo it all to incorporate a framework.

Answer (score 0):

The basic ideas to solving this well are:

Split your data retrieval from your display.

```
class Model { public function getData() {} }
class View { public function write() {} }
$model = new Model();
$view = new View();
$view->write($model->getData());
```

Implement Model::getData:

- Loop to build the sports that you are interested in so that you can OR them in a query.
- Get all of the results.
- Use PHP to order the array into sports.

Implement View::write:

- Loop over each sport, displaying it correctly.